# Why does my code say students is undefined if i clearly declare it within the function

Tags: python

Finally, print out the result of calling get_class_average with your students list. Your students should be [lloyd, alice, tyler].
Then, print the result of get_letter_grade for the class's average.
I am trying to print the results of this code. it keeps on saying students is undefined yet i clearly declare it. Please help.

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    total /= len(numbers)
    return total

def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student["homework"])
    quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
    tests = average(student["tests"])
    return 0.1 * homework + 0.3 * quizzes + 0.6 * tests

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >=70:
        return "C"
    elif score >=60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
    for student in students:
        results.append(get_average(student))
    return average(results)

print get_class_average(students)
print get_letter_grade(students)
```

Comment: If your problem can be isolated to one function, you should include only that function (and just enough code to be able to run it). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, look at your indentation. Your `print` commands aren't inside the `get_class_average` function.

Answer (score 1):

variable `students` is only defined in `get_class_average(students)`.

Thus, when the last 2 print lines ask for `students`, it said `students` are undefined. To solve the problem, you should move `students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]` out of the `get_class_average(students)`.

Logically, best place for the line of code would be after the line `# Add your function below!`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables that you define inside a function go into the local namespace of that function. It is not accessible outside the function .

Also in your case your case you are trying to to call the function with the students variable before defining it.

Move the definition do students outside the function , Example -

```
def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    for student in students:
        results.append(get_average(student))
    return average(results)

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
print get_class_average(students)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing anything with your function call. You have declared students within the function, but you are trying to call that variable from outside.

Since you do not have a global students variable, then the function calls that you have in the print statements are not finding a variable students.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, it's a scope issue with the `students` variable being defined inside the function, so students doesn't actually exist outside of it.

You shouldn't be passing `students` to `get_letter_grade`, but the result of what `get_class_average` returns as well:

```
averageScore = get_class_average([lloyd, alice, tyler])
averageGrade = get_letter_grade(averageScore)
print averageGrade
```

Outputs:

> B